# Using resource to populate scope property in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

**DISCLAIMER** I'm coming from knockout so I'm having a little trouble switching my train of thought on how to do certain things, this being one of them...

I have an `<input>` that a user can enter a movie title in and a list of movies should be displayed. The collection of movies is served up from my rest api by calling `http://www.example.com/api/movies?title=matrix`. The api is wrapped in an angular-resource module.

I thought that `$scope.movies = Movie.query({ title: $scope.searchValue });` would automatically update anytime `$scope.searchValue` changed but it doesn't appear to work that way.

```
angular.module('robotdog.resources', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Movie', function($resource){
        return $resource('/api/movies/:id');
    });

robotdog.controller('HomeController', function($scope, Movie){
    $scope.movies = Movie.query({ title: $scope.searchValue });

});
```

Just for the sake of completeness here is my markup for this particular controller...

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchValue" placeholder="Search Movie Title"/>
<pre>{{ movies | json }}</pre>
```

**What would be the correct way to populate `$scope.movies` with the search result after a user has entered a value in the `<input>`?**

Comment: are u getting response from server

Comment: if I type a value in the input and hit enter nothing happens. No request is sent and I get no error message in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only calling Movie.query once, when the controller is initialized.  You'll need to add a function to call Movie.query, and use that whenever the searchValue changes:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchValue" ng-change="getMovies" placeholder="Search Movie Title"/>


robotdog.controller('HomeController', function($scope, Movie) {
    $scope.getMovies = function() {
      $scope.movies = Movie.query({ title: $scope.searchValue });
    }
});
```

This will call your REST api whenever the user changes the input (i.e. on keypress), so if that causes too many RPCs you may want to add a 'search' button and only issue the RPC when it's hit:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchValue"/>
<button ng-click="getMovies">Go</button>
```

Comment: FTFY: `<button ng-click="getMovies()">Go</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchValue" />
<p ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter: searchValue">{{ movie }}</p>
```

No JS required in controller, apart from a basic query:

```
$scope.movies = Movie.query();
```

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/euan/zuhga76c/